# Format HTML to be suitable for JSON data C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to format some HTML to be sent to the client in a Javascript Object so it needs to have all line breaks removed. The whitespace is being removed fine but their still remains a line break even after the following lines:

```
string html = "";
html = Razor.Parse(template, viewdata);
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\n\s+(?=<)", "");
```

ie my html goes from this:

```
<h1>My Html</h1>
<div>
  <p>bla bla bla</p>
  <table>
    <!-- table content -->
  </table>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<h1>My Html</h1>
<div>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<table>
<!-- table content -->
</table>
</div>
```

but I need this:

```
<h1>My Html</h1><div><p>bla bla bla</p><table><!-- table content --></table></div>
```

how is \n being matched and not removed??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: Depending on the tags (esp. inline tags), you can't just remove all the new line, since it may remove some space in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `\s+` to `\s*` in your regex. `\s+` matches one or more space characters where `\s*` matches zero or more space characters.

```
\n\s*(?=<)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hC0qA9/1)

```
string str = @"<h1>My Html</h1>
<div>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<table>
<!-- table content -->
</table>
</div>";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?m)\n\s*(?=<)", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/7XwRW5)

Comment: yep, `\s+` matches one or more space characters including new line characters. But i always recommend you the regex in my answer because yours will remove also the inbetween spaces if a line has two consecutive tags like `<foo> <bar>`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=>)\s+
```

You can try this.See demo.Replace by `empty string`.

http://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/24